# Can I Store the JavaScript Map Object in Meteor's MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following code:

```
myMapField = new Map();

for (var i = stuff.length; i--; ) {
    myMapField.set(stuff.id, { name: stuff.name, type: Types.MY_TYPE });
}

Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
        $set: { 'profile.myMapField': myMapField }
    });
```

It doesn't work and the error message doesn't help ("undefined").

**Is there a way to store the JavaScript Map object in Meteor's MongoDB?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to insert a Map object into MongoDB as of now. A possible workaround that I can suggest is to :

1. Iterate over the Map object, and
2. Store the key-value pairs separately in the DB

The schema might look something like this:

```
{
  _id: someId,
  map: [{
         key: key1,
         value: value1
       },{
         key: key2,
         value: value2
       },{
         key: key3,
         value: value3
       },{
         key: key4,
         value: value4
       },{
         ...
       }]
}
```

Helper functions to convert Map objects into this format and vice-versa would have to be written to that effect.

Answer (score -1):

From your example you have a model like this:

```
const profile = {
  myMapField: {
    id: { name: "name1", type: "type1"}
  }
}
```

Then you have a map instead of an object cause you want to enjoy all the benefits of map. There isn't a schema type for `Map` but before inserting into your mongodb document, a way around it is to convert your map to plain object with a simple function.

```
const myMapField = new Map();

for (var i = stuff.length; i--; ) {
    myMapField.set(stuff.id, { name: stuff.name, type: Types.MY_TYPE });
}

const mapToObj = map => {
  let object = {};

  for (const [key, value] of map) {
    object[key] = value;    
  }

  return object;
}

const objectFromMap = mapToObj(myMapField);

console.log(objectFromMap) 
//{ id1: { name: 'id1', type: 'type1' }, id2: { name: 'id2', type: 'type2' } }

Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
  $set: { 'profile.myMapField': objectFromMap }
});
```

With this method you easily transform your map to an object and do your insert.

Comment: Notice that your insertion sequence will be lost if converted in this way.

Comment: @StanleyLuo could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @StanleyLuo never mind. ur right since es2015